# NextJS Head from string

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to set a next HEAD component to a string value (which is actually returned from woocommerce as a Yoast Head string)

Trouble is the content of the html string never gets added to the HEAD component!

There are other HEAD components above this but as I understand it it's additive?

```
 const Product = ({ product }) => {

  const classes = useStyles();
  const addToCart = useContext(BasketContext);

  return (
    <>
      <Head dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: product.yoast_head }} />
      <div className={classes.root}>

        <Grid container spacing={1}>
          <Grid item className={classes.grid} xs={6}>
            <Card addToCart={addToCart} product={product} />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <TabPanel product={product} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Update** I've got a fix for this with `html-react-parser` but I'll leave this open on the off chance someone has a better way!

Comment: I believe `next/head` does not take `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as a prop which usually only exists in browser DOM elements in React world.

Comment: Yeah I was being an idiot with that. Next != browser

Comment: If you have an answer feel free to post one, I was going to post my own this weekend failing anyone else. Ie if you've got a way of dynamically inserting a string into next head as html.

Comment: Oh, thought I had found the answer to my issue, but now... I will leave a link to my question here in case someone comes to answer this one and can actually answer the other one as well...: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64121456/next-js-how-to-add-a-link-tag-inside-the-head-with-literal-onload-attribut

Comment: Literally trying to do the exact same thing and can't yet... :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was trying to do the same thing and I was able to convert the YOAS Head block to a be parsed to react element array using "[html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser)"

```
import parse from 'html-react-parser'
...
const yoastHead = parse(bookDetail.yoast_head)
return (
    <Layout>
        <Head>
            {yoastHead}
        </Head>
        <h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: bookDetail.title.rendered }} />
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: bookDetail.content.rendered }} />
    </Layout>
)
```

Comment: Yep that's the one I used - will mark as correct since nobody else has come up with anything.

Comment: Are there any other ways without install a library?

Comment: Thanks after hours of trying different solutions 
Your solution is the best even ChatGbt was not able to resolve that problem