# Next.js - How to add a <link> tag inside the <head> with literal onload attribute string value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, head

On a Next.js project, I'd like to get some initial HTML with this exact same content inside the `<head>`:

```
<link href="..." rel="stylesheet" media="print" onload="this.media='all'" />
```

What I have in my code, inside Next.js's `<Head>` component, is:

```
{ /* @ts-ignore */ }
<link href="..." rel="stylesheet" media="print" onload="this.media='all'" />
```

Without the `@ts-ignore` it says:

> Property 'onload' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<LinkHTMLAttributes, HTMLLinkElement>'. Did you mean 'onLoad'? ts(2322)

And if I use `onLoad` instead of `onload` I get:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLLinkElement, Event>) => void'. ts(2322)

The problem is that the server-side generated HTML that I get has:

```
<link href="..." rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
```

And only once the page has rehydrated it updates to:

```
<link href="..." rel="stylesheet" media="all" onload="this.media='all'">
```

I've found this issue on GitHub but it doesn't help as I'm not using Google Fonts but Typography.com, so I can't use `next-google-fonts`: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12984

I'm thinking about adding a `ref` to that `link` tag and setting the attribute using `setAttribute`, which will hopefully work on the server-side as well, but wondering if there's a simpler way to do it.

Comment: What I'd do is create a component called link that wraps Next/Link then set the logic up in there. so you'd have Link-><a onload></a> - that way the events should work properly I think.

Comment: @Danziger did you find a solution for the problem? I ran into the exact same issue.

Comment: @RumTraubeNuss Yes, you can see this working here: https://andorratechvalley.com/. I have just added an answer with the solution. Hope it helps (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I eventually fixed this using a `<style>` tag with [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) in a [custom `_document.js`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document). All together it should look like this:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" crossOrigin="anonymous" />

<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@400;600&family=Karla:wght@700&display=swap" as="style" />

<style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {
  __html: `</style>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@400;600&family=Karla:wght@700&display=swap"
      media="print"
      onload="this.media='all';"
    />
    <style>`
} }></style>

<noscript>
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@400;600&family=Karla:wght@700&display=swap" />
</noscript>
```

Which generates the following output:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@400;600&amp;family=Karla:wght@700&amp;display=swap" as="style"/>

<style></style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@400;600&family=Karla:wght@700&display=swap" media="print" onload="this.media='all';" />

<style></style>

<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@400;600&amp;family=Karla:wght@700&amp;display=swap"/></noscript>
```

Not pretty, but better than having a `<div>` inside the `<head>` (which is not interpreted correctly by all browsers).

There's an [open RFC](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/129) to create a `RawHTML` component or extend `Fragment` to accept `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` so that something like this is possible without hacks, but it's been more than a year since it was created.

Also, there's [quite a long discussion about this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12014) as well with a few different solutions (hacks) that seem to work.

You can see the solution working here: https://andorratechvalley.com/

Comment: While this may be still be usable for other use cases, NextJS now has a better solution for [google fonts](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts#google-fonts) which will serve the fonts directly from your domain (no Google requests necessary). Also, to add a <link> tag, [<Head>](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/head) may be preferred.